# Log method execution time with .NET annotation

Tags: c#, .net, serilog

Is there any existing library to log the method execution time (I prefer serilog, anotar. serilog) just with method annotation?

Comment: https://github.com/Fody/MethodTimer / https://github.com/Fody/Anotar

Comment: @Selvin and other, this question already has answered but the topic of those questions is different, it is not related annotations what is the point of my question

Answer (score 0):

If your intention is to log elapsed time of the Controller/Action. You can write your own Middleware for this purpose. check the example below:

```
public class DiagnosticsMiddleware 
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

    public DiagnosticsMiddleware(RequestDelegate next, IElasticClient esClient)
    {
        _next = next;
        _esClient = esClient;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    { 
        Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();


        await _next(context);

        sw.Stop();
        var elapsedTime = sw.ElapsedTicks / (Stopwatch.Frequency / (1000L * 1000L));
        LogContext.PushProperty("ElapsedTime", elapsedTime);
    }

}
```

and you can configure it like

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    app.UseMiddleware<ContextEnricherMiddleware>();
}
```

Comment: There is no mention of the OP actually using ASP.NET. As posted, you can log the execution time of a controller call in ASP.NET, it cannot log the execution time of an arbitrary method.

Comment: edited my post accordingly